# Integral from 0 to 1 of a product of four Bessel functions

Tags: calculus, bessel-functions

I would like to solve this integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 J_d(\alpha x) J_c(\beta x) J_b( \gamma x) J_a(\rho x) x dx
\end{equation}

Where a, b, c, d are positive integers (including 0), and $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\rho$ are positive real numbers.

In fact, my real problem is to find the average in space between the multiplication of any 4 modes accepted in a multi-mode fiber:
\begin{equation}
E[ M_{nm} M_{n'm'} M_{n''m''} M_{n'''m'''}]
\end{equation}

Where each mode is defined in polar coordinates:
\begin{equation}
M_{nm} = J_m(u_n r /R) \cos( m\phi )
\end{equation}

where $\phi \in [0, 2\pi ]$ and $r \in [0, R ]$. Hence, the calculation of $E[ M_{nm} M_{n'm'} M_{n''m''} M_{n'''m'''}]$ can be separated into the radial integral and the angular integral. I already solved the angular one. Which tells me that $E[ M_{nm} M_{n'm'} M_{n''m''} M_{n'''m'''}]$ is not zero only if $m \pm m' \pm m'' \pm m''' = 0$. In this cases, that result is $\frac{\pi}{4}$. So I have the radial part left to solve, which is the one I state in this question.

It turn, I need to calculate $E[ M_{nm} M_{n'm'} M_{n''m''} M_{n'''m'''}]$ to calculate the variance of a light intensity pattern measured at the end facet of the multi-mode fiber.

Comment: Have you good reasons to think that it is  computable?

Comment: Not really, I just don't know. I haven't found integral tables with the solution to it so maybe it's not.